# Understanding string utils library

Tags: solidity, assembly

```
function toSlice(string memory self) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
        uint ptr;
        assembly {
            ptr := add(self, 0x20)
        }
        return slice(bytes(self).length, ptr);
    }
```

Hi. In the above toSlice code, I tried to print the **ptr** and no matter what string I pass it is always **160**. Can somebody tell me why is ptr always 160? And its significance?

Comment: This is probably because your string your is always declared at address 128 (0x80) and ptr is set to that address + 32 (0x20). But we'd need to see the code where you call `toSlice` to be sure.

Comment: Hi. This is from Library string utils. Okay. That makes sense. But when I declare ptr as an bytes variable it generates other values.

Comment: Also, you were right that if I equal ptr to self string, it gives 128. But my question is why is it so, does pointing a variable inside an assembly give its location?

Comment: Can you show your code please ? I'd be easier to provide you with an explanation that's appropriate regarding what you already have / have tried.

Comment: I was just checking StringUtils Library to learn about strings/assemblies.  This is the link: https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the free memory pointer is at 0x80 a described in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory).

You can verify it if you want by calling directly this function :

```
function test() public view returns(uint256 freeMemoryPointer) {
    assembly {
        freeMemoryPointer := mload(0x40)
    }
}
```

Which will return 128 (0x80) as everything before that is reserved (scratch space / free memory pointer / zero slot).

So when you declare a memory string, the first available address is 0x80 (assuming it is the first allocation).

The address of that string will hold a 32 byte value representing its length, the following 32 bytes slot (as many as required) will represent the actual characters of the string.

The following code reads a `uint256` at the address of the string, which actually holds its length, returning 12 in that case.

```
function test1() public view returns(uint256 stringLength) {

    string memory myString = "length is 12";

    assembly {
        stringLength := mload(myString)
    }

}
```

Now we have everything to answer your question about the `_ptr` member holding the value 160 (0xc0) :

- The string variable is declared at address 0x80 because it is the first allocation.
- 32 (0x20) bytes are used to store the string length
- So the actual data can only start at 128 (0x80) + 32 (0x20) = 160 (0xA0)

The library you are referring too does exactly that when it creates a slice with this code :

```
/*
 * @dev Returns a slice containing the entire string.
 * @param self The string to make a slice from.
 * @return A newly allocated slice containing the entire string.
 */
function toSlice(string memory self) internal pure returns (slice memory) {
    uint ptr;
    assembly {
        ptr := add(self, 0x20)
    }
    return slice(bytes(self).length, ptr);
}
```

Which essentially sets `ptr` to `self` (this is the address of the `self` variable in the case : 128 (0x80)) and adds 32 (0x20) to skip the slot holding the length, resulting in a `ptr` value of 160 (0xA0) which is really the pointer to the string data.

If you were to modify the free memory pointer by adding let's say 32 (0x20) to it and only then create your string / slice, you'd see a different value : 192 (0xC0) in that case :

```
function test2() public view returns (uint256) {

    // Add 32 to the free memory pointer
    assembly {
        mstore(0x40, add(mload(0x40), 0x20))
    }
    
    string memory myString = "This is a string";
    strings.slice memory mySlice = strings.toSlice(myString);

    return mySlice._ptr; // 192
}
```

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! This is such a lucid explaination. Can you point me towards some articles/group that you learnt all this. Or any techniques? I cant find a lot of resources

Comment: For solidity just use the docs (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/assembly.html & https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/yul.html) , those are technical specs after all.. it's just about knowing them. Having done some low level programming can help, solidity assembly / memory model is quite simple after all but it still requires a bit of work / playing around with it.